# Why do I get NULL on this query?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the max values from `kullnr` where the values of `ras` are 1, 2 and 3. But when I run this query, I get NULL on all three. Here's the code:

```
SELECT MAX( k1.kullnr ) , MAX( k2.kullnr ) , MAX( k3.kullnr )
FROM kull AS k1
JOIN kull AS k2 ON k1.kullnr = k2.kullnr
JOIN kull AS k3 ON k1.kullnr = k3.kullnr
WHERE k1.ras =0
AND k2.ras =1
AND k3.ras =2
```

If I run queries separated from each other, they work fine. For example:

```
SELECT MAX(kullnr) FROM kull WHERE ras=0
```

But due to extreme memory limitations, I can't run the queries separated. How can I make the single-query version work?

Comment: Do you have three rows where `.kullnr` is the same, and `.ras` has the values `1` `2` and `3`? Could we see a small set of data, and the answer you think you should get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your separate query

```
SELECT MAX(kullnr) FROM kull WHERE ras=0
```

You need

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ras = 0 THEN kullnr END  ) , 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ras = 1 THEN kullnr END  ) ,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ras = 2 THEN kullnr END  )
FROM kull 
WHERE ras  IN (0,1,2)
```

You are joining on `kullnr` so for each row all self joined tables will have the same value for this field but then you are selecting the `max` value from each of the three tables for this field. If the `JOIN` returns any rows at all then the `max` would be the same across all 3 columns.

Answer (score 2):

Unless all your maximum `kullnr` fields have the same value, you will get null because you have joined on the field you are trying to maximize.  I think this is more what you want:

```
SELECT k1.kullnr, k2.kullnr, k3.kullnr
FROM
(SELECT MAX(kullnr) AS kullnr FROM kull WHERE ras = 0) k1,
(SELECT MAX(kullnr) AS kullnr FROM kull WHERE ras = 1) k2,
(SELECT MAX(kullnr) AS kullnr FROM kull WHERE ras = 2) k3
```

I really don't think I would do this in this way, though, if I could help it.  If you do not need all the maximums in the same row, another query might be:

```
SELECT   ras, MAX(kullnr)
FROM     kull
GROUP BY ras
HAVING   ras = 0 OR ras = 1 OR ras = 2
```

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect. It seems to imply that the `MAX` is found then that value is used in the `JOIN`. Rather the JOIN restricts the rows first (presumably to an empty set in the OP's case) then the `MAX` is calculated. The (faulty) JOIN could potentially have still returned results if there were any `kullnr` values that had matching values for all there of the `ras` values.

Comment: @Martin Perhaps.  Admittedly, the SQL parser in my head pretty much just knows that what he was trying to do wouldn't work and would likely produce NULL values, but it seems like there would be some combination of data that would produce _something_.  Anyway, I'm hoping the last query with GROUP BY will suit the need better.

Comment: @Martin I didn't see your edit before writing my last comment.  Your explanation makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The query from Martin will get you the results you want.

As to WHY you got a null, the JOIN conditions are probably preventing any set of three rows from matching. They actually restrict the query to rows where the same kullnr is present in ras=0, ras=1 and ras=2

Comment: Or the query by Andrew which I've only just seen. I personally like the GROUP BY usage best and am giving it my vote